# File count - os.listdir vs ls | wc -l

Tags: python, linux

I was *trying to find the file count* when I got this,

Via terminal:

```
ls | wc -l
```

gave me the total of *58925 files*

[image: ls | wc -l]

And via Python's os module:

```
len(os.listdir('/home/cloud_user/notebooks/Zain/Data/Images/'))
```

gave me the total of *58926 files*

[image: python code]

*Why is there a difference between these two ? And which one is correct ?*

Comment: Have you tried doing this on a smaller directory and then counting which one is correct? That’s to answer the first part of your question, at least.

Comment: Yes, I have. Usually it give me same results. But as explained by @blhsing, the difference is due to the hidden file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Linux/UNIX, `ls` hides file names starting with a dot `.` unless you specify the `-a` option, so it's apparent that you have one file in the `Images` directory that starts with `.`, which `os.listdir` would account for but `ls` would not.